# Android RSS Application Model and Custom ListView Adapter - How to show all rss items?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have 2 classes

`Feed(id, title, url, ArrayList<Item> items)` 
`Item(id, title, description, pubDate, thumbnail)`

My CustomAdapter (Pseudocode)

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
Feed feed;
Context context;

public MyAdapter(Context context, Feed feed {
    this.context = context;
    this.feed = feed
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return feed.items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return feed.items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Item x = feed.items.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(x.getTitle());
    holder.description.setText(x.getDescription());

    holder.setFeedName(feed.getName());
}
```

}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView title, description, feedName;

```
ViewHolder(View v) {
    title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id....);
    description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id....);
    feedName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id....);
}
```

}

This works fine for selected Feeds. For example if i select to show CNN News feed items it works fine!!!!

But... if i want to show all articles from all feeds, or favorite articles it don't work! Any idea how to implement it?

Comment: You're gonna have to explain what doesn't work, what's the difference between the data sources and what you tried

Comment: i don't talk about code error. i talk about model logic. the above model just fetch rss articles for specific feed. Whati want is to add `show all` articles from any feed